# Reflection warning in code generated by Clojure macro

Tags: clojure, macros

I don't understand why the following code produces a reflection warning:

```clj
(set! *warn-on-reflection* true)

(defmacro my-macro [k] `(.length ~(with-meta k {:tag String})))

(defn my-fun1 [k] (my-macro k))
;; Reflection warning, /tmp/form-init2370243866132870536.clj:1:18 - reference to field length can't be resolved.
```

Using `macroexpand-1` shows that the generated code does have the typehint, and if I write the same code manually without using a macro, there is no reflection warning:

```clj
(set! *print-meta* true)

(macroexpand-1 '(my-macro k))
;; (.length ^java.lang.String k)

(defn my-fun2 [k] (.length ^String k))
;; All good, no reflection warning
```

Benchmarking the function shows that the warning is not just a red herring, the reflection actually occurs at runtime:

```clj
(time (reduce + (map my-fun1 (repeat 1000000 "test"))))
;; "Elapsed time: 3080.252792 msecs"

(time (reduce + (map my-fun2 (repeat 1000000 "test"))))
;; "Elapsed time: 275.204877 msecs"
```

Comment: When I run the `macroexpand-1` line, I don't see the type hint.  I think there's something wrong with the macro, however; it won't accept literal strings:  `(my-macro "foo") ;=> java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to clojure.lang.IObj`.

Comment: You should see the type hint. Are you sure you set `*print-meta*` to true?

Answer (score 3):

The tag should be a Symbol, not a Class. So the following code works:

```
(defmacro my-macro [k] `(.length ~(with-meta k {:tag `String})))
```

This is actually stated in the [documentation of special forms](http://clojure.org/special_forms):

> :tag
>
> **a symbol naming a class or a Class object** that indicates the Java
>   type of the object in the var, or its return value if the object is a
>   fn.

The fact that `macroexpand-1` shows a type hint that is invalid but looks exactly like the correct one is quite misleading :)

Comment: Note that it's slightly more correct to use a backquote on `String` there, not an ordinary quote. It will be the same for classes in java.lang, since those are imported in all namespaces and therefore the unqualified reference works, but if you try to use a class like ArrayList it will only work in namespaces that have imported java.util.ArrayList.